# Wordpress визуальный редактор для произвольного поля

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация следующая:

- Для записей добавил произвольное поле textarea (нужен доп блок вывода инфы).
- Создал функцию которая создает, отображает и сохраняет данные в произвольном поле.

В админке все отображается как надо. Как мне прикрутить к произвольному полю стандартный визуальный редактор Wordpress, чтобы пользователю было удобно пользоваться?

Answer (score 3):

Используй ф-цию [wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings)](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_editor);

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение на буржуйских форумах.
в functions.php добавляем следующий код
// Добавляем дополнительное поле

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_new_metaabox' ); 

function adding_new_metaabox(){   
    add_meta_box('html_myid_61_section', 'Прикрепить файлы', 

'my_output_function');
}

function my_output_function( $post ) {
    //so, dont ned to use esc_attr in front of get_post_meta
    $valueeee2=  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'SMTH_METANAME_VALUE' , true 

) ;
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2), 'mettaabox_ID_stylee', 

$settings = array('textarea_name'=>'MyInputNAME') );
}


function save_my_postdata( $post_id ){                   
    if (!empty($_POST['MyInputNAME'])){
        $datta=htmlspecialchars($_POST['MyInputNAME']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'SMTH_METANAME_VALUE', $datta );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_postdata' );
```

в single.php или в другом шаблоне в нужном месте выводим

```
<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'SMTH_METANAME_VALUE', true)); ?>
```

Comment: Способ хороший, но форматирование полностью игнорируется. А это значит в представленном вами коде, взятом в забугорном форуме нет смысла, и для правильной работы нужно дополнительно принудить его форматировать текст.
Так как "Прикрепить файлы", этот код отличается.
Изначальный вариант какой ? Возможно там автор и предоставил возможность форматировать текст. Ссылку было бы хорошо привести на источник, если сохраняли, конечно.